# whenever the page number is 1,the num_pages always gets 1,when the page number greater than 1,it works fine

Tags: python, django, django-templates, django-class-based-views

I am using django pagination,but i got a confused problem that whenever `page=1` and then the total number of pages gets 1.

When the page greater than 1,the total number of pages returns right number of pages.

For instance,

When i requests **http://127.0.0.1:8000/circle_admin/circle/1/posts?page=1**

**`Page {{ page_obj.number }} of {{ paginator.num_pages }}`**  is  **Page 1 of 1**

When i requests **http://127.0.0.1:8000/circle_admin/circle/1/posts?page=2**

**`Page {{ page_obj.number }} of {{ paginator.num_pages }}`**  is  **Page 2 of 4**

---

**PostView**

```
class PostView(LoginRequiredMixin, generic.ListView):
    template_name = 'circleadmin/circle_posts.html'
    model = Post
    queryset = Post.objects.all()
    paginate_by = 5

    def get_queryset(self):
        return super(PostView, self).get_queryset().filter(circle=self.kwargs['circle_id'], is_removed=False).order_by('-updated_time')
```

**Template.html**

```
{% if page_obj.has_previous %}
    <a href="?page={{ page_obj.previous_page_number }}">previous</a>
{% endif %}

<span class="current">
    Page {{ page_obj.number }} of {{ paginator.num_pages }}.
</span>

{% if page_obj.has_next %}
    <a href="?page={{ page_obj.next_page_number }}">next</a>
{% endif %}
```

---

I'm using Python 2.7 and Django 1.8.3

Anyone has an idea?Thanks for any answer.

Comment: I think there is typo is your class="current" html tag. it should be {{page_obj.num_pages}}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is because of i am using django-pagination-bootstrap and i add the codes:

**{% autopaginate object_list 10 %}**

when i removed the codes,it works fine.